# Database Query in debugger consistently showing over 2000ms

Tags: craft3, mysql, query, optimization

In trying to optimize my Craft 3 site, I have discovered that it's apparently taking longer than expected to query my database. The duration for the apparent culprit is typically between 1900 and 2300ms alone.

[image]

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
`kcu`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` AS `name`,
`kcu`.`COLUMN_NAME` AS `column_name`,
`tc`.`CONSTRAINT_TYPE` AS `type`,
CASE
    WHEN NULL IS NULL AND `kcu`.`REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() THEN NULL
    ELSE `kcu`.`REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA`
END AS `foreign_table_schema`,
`kcu`.`REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` AS `foreign_table_name`,
`kcu`.`REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` AS `foreign_column_name`,
`rc`.`UPDATE_RULE` AS `on_update`,
`rc`.`DELETE_RULE` AS `on_delete`,
`kcu`.`ORDINAL_POSITION` AS `position'
FROM
`information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS `kcu`,
`information_schema`.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` AS `rc`,
`information_schema`.`TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` AS `tc`
WHERE
`kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = COALESCE(NULL, DATABASE()) AND `kcu`.`CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` = `kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` AND `kcu`.`TABLE_NAME` = 'resourcepaths'
AND `rc`.`CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` = `kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` AND `rc`.`TABLE_NAME` = 'resourcepaths' AND `rc`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` = `kcu`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME`
AND `tc`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = `kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` AND `tc`.`TABLE_NAME` = 'resourcepaths' AND `tc`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` = `kcu`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` AND `tc`.`CONSTRAINT_TYPE` = 'FOREIGN KEY'
UNION
SELECT
`kcu`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` AS `name`,
`kcu`.`COLUMN_NAME` AS `column_name`,
`tc`.`CONSTRAINT_TYPE` AS `type`,
NULL AS `foreign_table_schema`,
NULL AS `foreign_table_name`,
NULL AS `foreign_column_name`,
NULL AS `on_update`,
NULL AS `on_delete`,
`kcu`.`ORDINAL_POSITION` AS `position`
FROM
`information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS `kcu`,
`information_schema`.`TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` AS `tc`
WHERE
`kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = COALESCE(NULL, DATABASE()) AND `kcu`.`TABLE_NAME` = 'resourcepaths'
AND `tc`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = `kcu`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` AND `tc`.`TABLE_NAME` = 'resourcepaths' AND `tc`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` = `kcu`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` AND `tc`.`CONSTRAINT_TYPE` IN ('PRIMARY KEY', 'UNIQUE')
ORDER BY `position` ASC
```

I'm not having much luck in figuring out how to fix this, and as I understand it, there's not a lot that can be done on Craft's end, but I'm at a loss as to where to go next. I've moved over to a VPN (Dreamhost) and I've added the following to my config/app.php:

```
return [
'components' => [
    'db' => function() {
        $config = craft\helpers\App::dbConfig();
        $config['schemaCacheDuration'] = 60 * 60 * 24; // 1 day
        return Craft::createObject($config);
    },
  ],
];
```

Any thoughts on where to go from here? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How many other databases are on the MySQL server that you're using?

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for responding. I have 10 other databases, but I know for a fact that three of them are attached to sites that are pretty much dead.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4037

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that. Added the bit of code Brandon had suggested. Moved to a VPS too. Beginning to think my host (Dreamhost) might be doing something weird. I just don't know. Thanks again for the response.